# Git: How to make a new commit and push the branch head forward to it?

Tags: git

I did

```
git checkout commit_id
git push origin feature/my_feature_branch
```

to revert the last 2 commits, then modified several files

now with

```
git status
```

I get

```
HEAD detached at commit_id

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
 .... list of add/remove/edits ....
```

(commit_id is same as above)

**how do I push the latest modifications so that HEAD on the current feature branch, matches the new commit I'm going to create** by

```
commit -a
git push origin feature/my_feature
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in general by

```
git checkout <commit-id>
git branch -D feature/my_feature    #Delete the branch
git checkout -b feature/my_feature  #checkout new branch with same name as deleted branch 
git push origin -f                  #force push to origin
```

There are probably cleaner ways to do this as well (without first deleting). However, this is a simple one that I always use.

However... Force pushing is not a very good idea if someone else might also be using your branch!!!

In case you are only deleting commits from a branch (as in your scenario)

```
git checkout feature/my_feature
git rebase master -i
#delete all commits you don't want from the file that opens
bit push origin -f
```

Comment: I know forcing push is not good but I'm using git on my own repository just for backup and version tracking. It worked. thanks :) However it required me to commit the latest changed (by commit -a) before pushing again (first block of code you provided). Also I didn't get how do I actually delete the commits without force pushing (2nd block of code)?